# Why is ⎕SIGNAL not caught by :: error guards?

Tags: error-handling, scope, apl, dyalog

```
      {11::¯1 ⋄ 2÷0}⍬
¯1
      {11::¯1 ⋄ ⎕SIGNAL 11}⍬
DOMAIN ERROR
```

Why is the first signal caught, while the second is not?

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation for `⎕SIGNAL`](https://help.dyalog.com/17.1/Content/Language/System%20Functions/signal.htm) (my emphasis):

> The state indicator is ***cut back to exit from the function*** or operator containing the line that invoked `⎕SIGNAL`, or is cut back to exit the Execute (`⍎`) expression that invoked `⎕SIGNAL`. If executed within a nested dfn, the state indicator is cut back to exit from the capsule containing the line that invoked `⎕SIGNAL`. An error is then generated.

In other words, by the time `⎕SIGNAL` is done doing its thing, we're already outside the dfn and thus the dfn's error guard (`::`) is not in effect any more.

To work around this, you have to use `⎕SIGNAL` in a separate capsule. For example, you can define a cover function *outside* the function where you want to use it:

```
      Signal←{⎕SIGNAL ⍵}
      {11::¯1 ⋄ Signal 11}⍬
¯1
```

Alternatively, you can put `⎕SIGNAL` in its own execution capsule:

```
      {11::¯1 ⋄ ⍎'⎕SIGNAL 11'}⍬
¯1
```